# User Roles in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

What is the most effective method to add User roles in Laravel 5.5?

I came across a couple of methods i.e.

- Admin Middleware
- Pivot Table for user_roles

I've tried and implemented both methods in my application but asking this question by keeping in mind my application's scalability on how they would be effective.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission - this package is pretty good tbh

Comment: Could you please expand on what you mean by `Admin Middleware`? Did you plan on just hardcoding user id's in a middleware or create an admins table? Please also be aware that this question might be seen as primarily opinion based, which tends to be off-topic for SO.

Comment: Here another package, called [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust).

Comment: You can try this package.. this is a good one https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0

Comment: also https://backpackforlaravel.com/

Comment: @milo526 you create a new middleware for Admin and uses it in your routes for authorization stuff, its a simple way to do it but I'm not sure if its the better approach.

Comment: You did you want to see if somebody is an admin in your middle ware?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can add permissions on role table create a new permission table to define permissions to user.

Eg:

```
Without permission table: Based on cartalyst sentinel
User Table -> name, email, password etc
Role Table -> name, slug, permissions
Users_role -> user_id, role_id

With permission table: Based in Zizaco entrust
User Table -> name, email, password etc
Role Table -> name, slug, permissions
Users_role -> user_id, role_id
Permission table -> name, slug, description
role_permission -> permission_id, role_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to reinvent the wheel? Mayb you can use a package for that. The [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package is one I particulary like.

After a quick search I also found this [discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/which-package-is-best-for-roles-permissions) on laracasts with a few other options.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel here, just asking for whats the better approach of the two. ! :)

Comment: Ah okay. Depends on what you want to accomplish. Admin middleware just gives you one on/off switch. If that's enough you should use that. If you want to have more flexibility you generally want to switch to something with roles.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to have both: the middleware to check for access on each request & the permissions table (& pivot) for storing your permissions.

For a working example, you could:

- take a look here at a [package](https://github.com/laravel-enso/RoleManager) that is part of
- a bigger [app](https://github.com/laravel-enso/Enso), and try out
- a [working demo](https://www.laravel-enso.com/login)

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to these packages.

In the above examples, in brief, permissions are tied to a role, which can be assigned to an owner,  and the owner has users.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks that you need both of things mentioned in your question. You should have a Roles table that defines all possible roles a user can have in your application.
A user_roles pivot table that you would use to associate users to particular roles
And a Middleware which you will use to check for roles before authorizing user to access the functionality.

Detained demo is given in this link for roles based authentication in Laravel 5.5 https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/